# TimeZone issue in Java XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, time, timezone, datetime-format

I hope this is not a repeat.
I checked other searches here and all of them seem to talk about "displaying" the date in the right TimeZone format using SimpleDateFormat.

However, my problem is I obtain an XMLGregorianCalendar Object which is let us say in "CET".

I have to find out the format from this object and send the current time also in the same TimeZone as the server.

For eg: I need an XMLGregorianCalendar Object that returns me in this format(with Timezone):

2012-09-19T15:23:36.421+02:00

So I just tried this following snippet which seems to only return the time in local Timezone :(

```
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET");
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
df.setTimeZone(utc);
System.out.println(" - Gregorian UTC [" + df.format(gc.getTime()) + "]")

XMLGregorianCalendar currServTime = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);

System.out.println("currServTime is "+currServTime);
```

Comment: Should this read `TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");` not CET?

Comment: Sure. I was trying out varous example strings just to be sure!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should include the time zone you're interested in in the `GregorianCalendar`, either by passing it to [the constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28java.util.TimeZone%29) or by [setting it afterwards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29). So either of these lines should work for you:

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(utc);
gc.setTimeZone(utc);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it before. But the problem was my output read:2012-09-19T15:23:36.421Z

Comment: @user907810: *Why* do you consider that a problem? [The specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-timezones) clearly indicate that `Z` is a correct and canonical representation for the UTC time zone, i.e. one with zero offset from UTC. If you want some non-canonical alternative, like `+00:00`, you'll have to perform a string replacement or similar.

Comment: thanks. in fact whent I tried est, I got the +5:00 like you mentioned. perhaps utc with z is the standard

Comment: Yes, UTC with `Z` is the canonical form. Formulations like `+00:00` or `-00:00` are valid as well, but the one with `Z` is preferred. The link from my previous comment says as much.